# Ler um Array ou Bulk Collect como tabela em um PLSQL Oracle

Tags: sql, array, oracle, pl-sql, oracle11g

Como carrega um Array ou Bulk em um PLSQL e depois ler isto como uma tabela.

Exemplo

```
DECLARE
  VA_ARRAY ....DEFINIÇÃO DO ARRAY
  VN_QTD NUMBER;
BEGIN
  -- TABELA01 É UMA TABELA FÍSICA EXISTENTE NO BANCO
  SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO VA_ARRAY FROM TABELA01;
  --AQUI QUERY FAZER UM JOIN DE OUTRA TABELA COM O ARRAY GERADO
  -- TABELA02 É UMA OUTRA TABELA FÍSICA EXISTENTE NO BANCO
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO VN_QTD
  FROM TABELA02 , (VA_ARRAY) COMO TABELA
  WHERE TABELA02.COLUNA01 = (VA_ARRAY).CAMPO ...;
END;
```

Poderia usar um subselect sei , mas no caso a SQL de fato seria muito pesada por isto queria tentar usar a tabela em memória, a documentação da Oracle é farta mas ruim de pequenos exemplos , se alguém souber um modo simples agradeço qualquer ajuda.

O exemplo em si não creio ser importante e sim a dúvida , como ler um "array" como uma tabela em um SQL em um bloco ou objeto PLSQL ?

Answer (score 2):

Eu acho que o que precisa para preencher o array é isto no DECLARE:
**type tab01_type is table of tabela01%rowtype;** (SEM INDICAÇÃO DO INDEX BY)
depois, crie uma variável baseada nesse tipo:
**v_tab01_array tab01_type;**

E o bulk collect já funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Veja isso:

```
DECLARE
   howmany NUMBER;
   some_first employees.first_name%TYPE;
   some_last employees.last_name%TYPE;
   some_employee employees%ROWTYPE;
   TYPE first_typ IS TABLE OF employees.first_name%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
   TYPE last_typ IS TABLE OF employees.first_name%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
   first_names first_typ;
   last_names last_typ;
   CURSOR c1 IS SELECT first_name, last_name FROM employees;
   TYPE name_typ IS TABLE OF c1%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
   all_names name_typ;
   TYPE emp_typ IS TABLE OF employees%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
   all_employees emp_typ;
BEGIN
-- Query a single value and store it in a variable.
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO howmany FROM user_tables;
   dbms_output.put_line('This schema owns ' || howmany || ' tables.');

-- Query multiple columns from one row, and store them in variables.
   SELECT first_name, last_name INTO some_first, some_last
      FROM employees WHERE ROWNUM < 2;
   dbms_output.put_line('Random employee: ' || some_first ||
      ' ' || some_last);

-- Query a single row and store it in a record.
   SELECT * INTO some_employee FROM employees WHERE ROWNUM < 2;

-- Query multiple columns from multiple rows, and store them in a collection
-- of records.
   SELECT first_name, last_name BULK COLLECT INTO all_names FROM EMPLOYEES;

-- Query multiple columns from multiple rows, and store them in separate
-- collections. (Generally less useful than a single collection of records.)
   SELECT first_name, last_name
      BULK COLLECT INTO first_names, last_names
      FROM EMPLOYEES;

-- Query an entire (small!) table and store the rows
-- in a collection of records. Now you can manipulate the data
-- in-memory without any more I/O.
   SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO all_employees FROM employees;
END;
/
```

Comment: na realidade o que eu queria era carregar uma "bulk" e depois fazer um join de uma tabela com esta "bulk" a lendo como se fosse uma tabela.

Answer (score -2):

Neste caso eu uso tabelas temporárias. Os dados inseridos, alterados ou excluídos nelas são visíveis apenas na sua sessão do Oracle. Quando a sessão morrer TUDO é apagado. Para criar uma tabela temporária basta usar a palavra chave TEMPORARY no create table: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE  ....

Comment: Isto ou uma GTT (Global Temporary Tables) mas queria saber se daria para fazer "join" de array com tabelas , um CASDT talvez , valeu.